# PyQt: Dragging item from list view and dropping to table view, the drop index is always -1

Tags: python, qt, drag-and-drop, pyqt, pyqt4

In my code I have successfully implemented Drag n Drop from one QListView to another QListView and internal move is also working fine. 
Now, due to a necessity, I have modified view that accepts drops i.e. I am trying to Drag from QListView to QTableView instead.

The issue is, when I dropped on QTableView, every time it prints invalid index i.e. -1 (printing that in dropEvent().

In my previous implementation between list views, even when the item was dropped in between items, the index was appropriately updated. This is not the case here. Thanks for answering.

```
class SerialTestStepListView(QtGui.QTableView):
    itemSelectionChanged = pyqtSignal()
    casualSignal3 = pyqtSignal()
    casualSignal4 = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self,parent = None):
        QListView.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        # Hide column here......
        self.setSelectionMode(self.SingleSelection) 
        self.setDragDropMode(self.InternalMove)
        self.setSelectionBehavior(self.SelectRows)

    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasFormat("application/xml-chirag"):
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()

    def dragMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasFormat("application/xml-chirag"):
            event.setDropAction(QtCore.Qt.MoveAction)
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        data = event.mimeData()
        bstream = data.retrieveData("application/xml-chirag", QtCore.QVariant.ByteArray)
        selected = pickle.loads(bstream)
        index = self.indexAt(event.pos()).row()
        print("into the drop event")
        print(index)  # This is printing -1
        print(self.indexAt(event.pos()))
        self.emit(SIGNAL("casualSignal3"),selected, index)
        event.accept()

    def startDrag(self, event):
        indx = self.indexAt(event.pos())
        index = indx.row()
        print("into the drag event")
        self.emit(SIGNAL("casualSignal4"),indx, index)
        if not indx.isValid():
            pass
        else:
            return True

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        self.startDrag(event)
```

Model is:

```
class SerialTestListModel(QtCore.QAbstractListModel):

    def __init__(self, testStep = [], parent = None):
        QtCore.QAbstractListModel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.__TestSteps = testStep

    def rowCount(self, parent):
        return len(self.__TestSteps)

    def flags(self, index):
        if index.isValid():
            return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsDragEnabled | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsDropEnabled | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled | QtCore.Qt.MoveAction
        else:
            return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsDragEnabled | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsDropEnabled  | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled

    def data(self, index, role):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            row = index.row()
            return self.__TestSteps[row]

    def setData(self, index, value, role = QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            self.dataChanged.emit(index,index)
            return True
        return False

    def insertRows(self, position, rows, selected, parent = QtCore.QModelIndex()):

        if selected is None:
            pass
        else:
            if ((position == -1) and (selected is not None)):
                position = self.rowCount(parent)
            self.beginInsertRows(parent, position, position + rows - 1)
            for i in range(rows):
                self.__TestSteps.insert(position, selected)        
            self.endInsertRows()
            return True

    def removeRows(self, position, rows, parent = QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        if position == -1:
            pass
        else:
            self.beginRemoveRows(parent, position, position + rows - 1)
            for i in range(rows):
                value = self.__TestSteps[position]
                self.__TestSteps.remove(value)
            self.endRemoveRows()
            return True
```

Controller part:

```
SerialTestStepListViewHdlr = CTC.SerialTestStepListView()
    SerialTestStepListViewHdlr.show()
    SerialTestStepListViewHdlr.connect(SerialTestStepListViewHdlr, SIGNAL("casualSignal3"), acceptDrag)


def acceptDrag(selected, index):
    SerialTestStepListModel = mod.SerialTestListModel(testStep)
    #selected = str(selected)
    SerialTestStepListModel.insertRows(index, 1, selected)
    SerialTestStepListViewHdlr.setModel(SerialTestStepListModel)
```

Answer (score 2):

This was resolved after replacing:

```
index = self.indexAt(event.pos()).row()
```

with

```
index = self.rowAt(event.pos().y())
```

in dropEvent() method.